# How to select a specific TPU in Google Cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, tpu

I'm trying to use TPUs on Google cloud and I'm trying to figure out how to specify the right  TPU to use. I'm trying to following the quickstart

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart

But it doesn't say how to select a TPU, it only gives instructions to select a region.

```
$ ctpu up --zone=us-central1-b  \
--tf-version=2.1 \
--name=tpu-quickstart
```

I am wondering how to select a v2-32 . At first I figured I should just specify `us-central1-a` but I noticed regions can hold more than one TPU type here

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/types-zones

For example, `us-central1-a` has both v2-128 and v2-32,  so I'm not exactly sure that the region alone can specify the TPU type. I'm sorta of afraid of accidentally spinning up a paid TPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the TPU type by using the `tpu-size` parameter, as per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/creating-deleting-tpus#setup_VM_only) (also [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/types-zones#accelerator-type)).

For example:

```
ctpu up --zone=us-central1-a  \
--tf-version=2.1 \
--name=tpu-quickstart \
--tpu-size=v2-32
```

Remember that only `v2-8` and `v3-8` [are available](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/pricing#pod-pricing) unless you have access to evaluation quota or have purchased a commitment.

Comment: I have been given some TPU credits for TFRC. Do you know if  there something I need to do to use those credits specifically?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the details of [that program](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfrc).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `gcloud` command to create TPUs

```
gcloud compute tpus create tpu-quickstart \
      --zone=us-central1-a \
      --network=default \
      --accelerator-type=v2-32 \
      --version=2.1
```